# Wordpress shortcode not working (theme issue)

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

My theme is not supporting shortcodes on this moment and I would like to resolve this issue. Could you guys help me out? To be clear, shortcodes DO work on OTHER themes.

I'm using the Brooklyn Indie Band theme, which is not good supported by the author (my mistake). It's a onepage template which uses pages to show the different sections on the page.

When using a shortcode, it literally shows the shortcode.

How can I solve this problem? Do you guys have any idea?

Website: http://www.avito.nl/dudettes/

Thank you.

Greets,
Kjie

Comment: What is the shortcode like? What is the name of the theme? Meer informatie alsjeblieft :)

Comment: The shortcode I'm using is [gigpress_shows]. The template is 'Brooklyn Indie Band'. No shortcode is working.